# A many-to-many primary key for "appointments"

Tags: mysql, database

I know this question has been asked a lot but my example seems different.

I have two entities: Doctor and Client, and a many-to-many relationship between them to create the entity Appointment, which has, say "appointment_date_time" for an attribute.

I'm using the foreign keys from Doctor and Client to create a composite primary key in Appointment, but since there can be many appointments between the same doctor and person, should the "date_time" *also* be included as part of the primary key so there's no duplicates? Or would the two foreign keys be enough to query off of?

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you want to factor in parallel universes, that might be a good idea :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PRIMARY KEY needs to always be unique, so including the datetime would make an usable composite PRIMARY KEY that would (probably, unless you could have multiple appointments at the same time for 2 different purposes, which might happen) be unique.

However this is unlikely the best approach practically speaking, as if they move the appointment then this time will change (or maybe changed the doctor). Then you have no way to reference the appointment statically, say for example if you associated some extra data to it during creation or had to reference it as an audit entry.  It also means any references to it that you do create would need to store all 3 columns.

As such I would simply look to create an auto incrementing primary key in this case, and simply index on both doctor and client for fast searches.